# WinForms Bitmap region is already locked

Tags: c#, winforms, exception, bitmap, byte

I'm trying to slide through a few images basically you have 2 buttons forward and backwards. They're function is to scroll through a list images. Once one of them reaches the end it must go back to the other side of the list. Here's what I have

```
private List<Bitmap> RotatePacks = new List<Bitmap> { new Bitmap(@"Assets\All_Cards\All_Royal\All_Royal.png"),
                                                        new Bitmap(@"Assets\All_Cards\All_Classic\All_Classic.jpg")};

private void bNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap currentImage = (Bitmap)pickCards.Image;
    for (int i = 0; i < RotatePacks.Count; i++)
    {
        if (AreEqual(currentImage, RotatePacks[i]))
        {
            try
            {
                pickCards.Image = RotatePacks[i + 1];
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                bPrevious_Click(sender, e);
                pickCards.Image = RotatePacks[i - 1];
            }
        }
    }
}
private void bPrevious_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Bitmap currentImage = (Bitmap)pickCards.Image;
    for (int i = 0; i < RotatePacks.Count; i++)
    {
        if (AreEqual(currentImage, RotatePacks[i]))
        {
            try
            {
                pickCards.Image = RotatePacks[i - 1];
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                bNext_Click(sender, e);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Those are the 2 buttons. Here I'm trying to compare the image of the pictureBox that's holding the images with the list `RotatePacks`. Like this im getting the current image that is being shown. Here's the AreEqual method :

```
public unsafe static bool AreEqual(Bitmap b1, Bitmap b2) // copy pasted
{
    if (b1.Size != b2.Size)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (b1.PixelFormat != b2.PixelFormat)
    {
        return false;
    }

    /*if (b1.PixelFormat != PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb)
    {
        return false;
    }*/
    Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, b1.Width, b1.Height);
    BitmapData data1
        = b1.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, b1.PixelFormat);
    BitmapData data2
        = b2.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, b1.PixelFormat);
    int* p1 = (int*)data1.Scan0;
    int* p2 = (int*)data2.Scan0;
    int byteCount = b1.Height * data1.Stride / 4; //only Format32bppArgb 

    bool result = true;
    for (int i = 0; i < byteCount; ++i)
    {
        if (*p1++ != *p2++)
        {
            result = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    b1.UnlockBits(data1);
    b2.UnlockBits(data2);

    return result;
}
```

So now back to my problem the buttons are working just the way i want them but they work just once. If i press button next and than button previous or i press the next button twice the program will crash. It gives me the exception here

```
            BitmapData data2
            = b2.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, b1.PixelFormat);
```

Here's some screenshots of the actual exception :

http://prntscr.com/9ug3nl

http://prntscr.com/9ug3vv

- P.S Im using this comparing method but i haven't program it. I copied the code from another StackOverflow question

Comment: This is just a wild guess now... but don't you think it is worth to have an early check `if (b1 == b2) return true;`? Likely `b1 == b2` will cause that problem...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be a couple of issues here:

1. It is worth to have an early check

   ```
   if (b1 == b2) //put this
       return true; 
   //do something else
   Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, b1.Width, b1.Height);
   //and so on
   ```

   Likely `b1 == b2` will cause that problem
2. Seems like your `LockBits` refer to the same exact items (same `rect`, same size, some mode, same pixel format):

   ```
   Rectangle rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, b1.Width, b1.Height);
   BitmapData data1
       = b1.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, b1.PixelFormat);
   BitmapData data2
       = b2.LockBits(rect, ImageLockMode.ReadOnly, b1.PixelFormat);
   ```

   This could be another cause of the issue...

Comment: The early check did the job thanks a thousand times ! :)

Comment: @Assim so, that was the culprit all along... ;) glad to know that

Answer (score 0):

Like Ian pointed out you have to check if the images you are trying to compare in `AreEqual()` method (the `current image` and the one in `Rotatepacks[i]`) are identical AND belong to the same instance or not? IF they belong to the same instance it'd obviously generate that exception. Use the `.Equals()` method to check if the images belong to the same instance.

Consider an image instance

`Bitmap img;`

The image in `img` is loaded into the picture box as well as in the `RotatePacks`. In your code you are trying to lock that same instance twice so it generates an exception
The bitmap lines Ian pointed are ok tho.., 2 different images can have the same size and pixel format.

Also if that really was the case, i don't think you need to compare pixel by pixel. I suppose you have `Bitmap` instances in `Rotatepacks`. Just compare your image instance in picture box with the one in `Rotatepacks` using `.Equals()`